# XSL using parameter for-each

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt

I am using an XSL stylesheet to transform an xml document to html in an android environment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list> 
  <project id="Proj02"> 
    <observation id="Proj02_Obs001"> 
    …
    </observation> 
  </project>  
  <project id="Proj01"> 
    <observation id="Proj01_Obs002"> 
    …
    </observation>  
    <observation id="Proj01_Obs001">
      …
    </observation>
  </project> 
</list>
```

For my html file, I want to iterate through all observation of a specific project. To do that, I pass a parameter for project@id:

```
transformer.setParameter("projID", "Proj01")
```

Using the xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:param name="projID" />
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left">ID</th>
                        …
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="list/project[@id=$projID]/observation">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                            </td>
                            …
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting no results.

How do I need to modify this line?

```
<xsl:for-each select="list/project[@id=$projID]/observation">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are passing in an external parameter to a stylesheet, the `xsl:param` statement needs to be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="projID" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="list/project[@id=$projID]/observation">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The parameter is then global, and can be used throughout the stylesheet.

Comment: Wow, great! Thanks for this very quick answer. Works for me!